# easy partial differential equations with countable many solutions

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Hei,
I´m completely new in the topic of partial differential equations. Our teacher ask us to find a easy example of **a PDG of order one with countable(infinite) many solutions**.

But all easy examples, which comes into my mind like $u(x,y)=:u, u_{xx}=0  \Rightarrow u(x,y)=x*f(x)+g(y)$ with $f,g$ arbitary functions have uncountable many solutions.

Another guess is the example $u:=u(x_1,x_2,..,x_n)$$$  \nabla u=0$$
The solutions are all constant functions on a convex domain. If i have the intitial condition that the function must be a rational number i may have countable many solutions? But i guess, it isn´t a good example.